.NET Core / EF Core : join tables depending on content
So we have this legacy system we are writing new software do, the database structure is as it is, we can't refactor.
I would like a good way of finding Modules attached to my subscription with one db call, but here is the tricky part.
The ModuleType referee to the type of the module, each type has its own table.
We have tables like module_type1, module_type2 etc.
So the only way to make sure I get the current module via the pivot is knowing the type via ModuleTypee and then where moduleType1.id == ModuleId.
public class Subscription 
{
    public List<ModuleSubscriptionPivot> Modules { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleSubscriptionPivot
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int ModuleType { get; set; } 
    public int ModuleId { get; set; } //Id of ModuleType table
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; } 
    public ModuleType1 ModuleType1 { get; set; } //does this make sense? only one of Module1/2 properties would contain anything
    public ModuleType2 ModuleType2 { get; set; } 
}

public class ModuleType1
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleType2
{
    public string XXX { get; set; }
}

If I want to get my subscription with modules (including info in the pivot), how can I get the concrete ModuleType1/2 as well?

Can you provide the relevant DB schema for this?

Tip: if you need to do that in a single call to the database it would be best to use a raw SQL query, then add the data to a viewmodel and send it to the view or controller. if you need to reuse logic from already built models, you can invoke them using the Ids returned in the viewmodel
